# Payouts to Multiple Vendors on Marketplaces

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, marketplace

How do big e-commerce businesses do payouts to multiple vendors/merchants when people make purchases of multiple sellers. Most e-commerce giants have multiple onboarding methods. For example Wish allows you to onboard as a seller through PayPal, Payoneer, and like 6 other chinese payment gateways.

On the front-end, they always allow cards and PayPal for transactions. What do you do if you have 5 sellers, and 4 of them are on PayPal, and 1 of them is on Payoneer. How do you split that payment? I ask this question because I'm trying to find out how you do payouts to sellers on marketplaces when people can be onboarded to multiple different gateways on the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Payouts is for sending money from your own account(s) to others. Are you actually asking about such payout functionality, or are you asking about how to implement a marketplace that facilitates payments from customers to sellers.

In any case, if you are integrating different services then those are simply separate integrations.

Answer (score 0):

If the use case is to spilt a USD 100 payment into 2 parts and settle it to two different vendors across two platforms.

It will require two things
(i) build a business logic using the settlement APIs over and above the integrations of various Payout solution providers
(ii) accept the total amount (USD 100) paid by customers on a single source account prior to settlement to different vendors